# Как реализовать такую шкалу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

подскажите, как можно реализовать такую шкалу?

Comment: Можно использовать HTML и CSS, также можно в дополнении использовать JS. Также есть библиотеки jquery как вариант и многие другие где есть похожий функционал

Comment: а что за библиотеки?

Comment: Owl-carusel, SlickJS (это первое что пришло на ум из библиотек) также с помощью тега canvas. Вообще способов реализовать много, можно и с другими поработать например такими как GSAP JS. Все зависит от вас